# Android SDK instance Error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am not able to open android device manager in visual studio 2017.

***Android SDK Instance Error***

Android SDK Tools version 25.2.5 is not supported.
Update your Android SDK Tools to version 26.0.0 or newer.
We will open Xamarin Android SDK manager for you.

Where & how update **Android SDK Tools to version 26.0.0**?
After complete visual studio update not able to get it.

Component Installed Details....

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.8.0
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.0+28010.0
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

Installed Version: Professional

Xamarin   **4.11.0.732** (d15-8@33e83e124)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.14.218 (79f535bdd)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   1.1.113 (e1d02a7)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   **9.0.0.18** (HEAD/3d8a28f1a)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

[image]

Comment: Use the "Android SDK Manager" to update it.

Comment: How can i use it please share some screenshot, because when i open **Android SDK Manager** it showing empty, with error loading **SDK** component information failed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin

Comment: But i am not able to getting list in "android SDK manager".

Comment: I have used proxy behind internet connection, this create problem or not in my case.